# C# CPU usage separate (child) winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, cpu-usage

I know you can get the total CPU usage for a single process as I have below, but I was wondering if it were at all possible to get the CPU usage for each individual form in an application.

```
using (PerformanceCounter pCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName))
{
    pCounter.NextValue();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Process: {0}, CPU: {1}%", Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName, pCounter.NextValue());
}
```

Would it be possible to use something like the code above to get the CPU usage for individual forms in an application or is this simple not possible - or too much work for results?

Comment: For what purpose? General performance tweaking or are you looking for a bug?

Comment: @Kye I'm making a custom shell and was wondering if I could get CPU usage for my forms this way but it seems not so I will have to re-think my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work carried out in a process is not limited to doing work on a Form. A form is merely an User Interface object that you can use to launch any number of threads and back ground tasks that are all part of the process. You can create hundreds of forms, and then do nothing - and the process cpu usage will be essentially zero (except for the odd redraw). On the other hand you can create one form that launches a separate thread that does some CPU intensive work in the background and the CPU usage will shoot up. But that usage is not directly attributable to that Form.

Comment: I never actual looked at it this way. Thanks for this.